# How in error handling action determine should I return web view or api response

Tags: error-handling, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

In Asp.net Core project  I have both web UI and Web API controllers.
I  followed https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/handling-errors-in-asp.net-core-web-api article and included in startup.cs:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/error/{0}");
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/error/500");
```

And added error handling action in ErrorController:

```
[Route("error/{code}")]
public IActionResult Error(int code)
{
    return new ObjectResult(new ApiResponse(code));
}
```

This is good for web api, but not for web pages. For api we want to return custom object (serialised as JSON) , but for UI we want to return  custom view.
I want to write something like

```
public IActionResult Error(int code)
{
     if(CalledFromApiClient())
     {
           return new ObjectResult(new ApiResponse(code));
     }
     else
        return View(“Error”);
}
```

The question is how to implement CalledFromApiClient?

I am thinking to keep all api controllers in api subfolder/namespace and use callstack  to find was exception thrown from api controller or not.
It should work, but it doesn’t look good.

Is any better way?

Comment: Check Accept header (Content negotiation) If request asks for JSON give it JSON. If it asks for HTML then return that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found an answer in the blog of the same author https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/conditional-middleware-based-on-request-in-asp.net-core

> A common example for this requirement is a project with both MVC and
>   API actions where you want to error handling to be different for each.

We assume that url paths follow the convention that api controller actions Start WithSegment "api"

```
// returns Api error response
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/apierror/{0}");
appBuilder.UseExceptionHandler("/apierror/500");
});
// returns MVC error page
app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
appBuilder.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500");
});
```